# Is it safe to call Add on SortedDictionary in one thread and get Item in another?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, locking

I'm working on making my SortedDictionary thread safe and the thing I'm not sure about is: is it safe to have a call to add to SortedDictionary in one thread, like this:

```
dictionary.Add(key, value);
```

and simply get an item from this dictionary in another thread, like this:

```
variable = dictionary[key];
```

There is no explicit enumeration in either of those places, so it looks safe, but it would be great to be sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe to read and write `SortedDictionary<K,V>` concurrently: adding an element to a sorted dictionary may involve re-balancing of the tree, which may cause the concurrent read operation to take a wrong turn while navigating to the element of interest.

In order to fix this problem you would need to either wrap an instance of `SortedDictionary<K,V>` in a class that performs explicit locking, or roll your own collection compatible with the interfaces implemented by `SortedDictionary<K,V>`.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Anything that modifies the tree is not thread safe at all.  The trick is to fill up the SortedDictionary in one thread, then treat it as immutable and let multiple threads read from it.  (You can do this with a SortedDictionary, as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).  I mention this because there may be a collection/dictionary/map out there somewhere that is changed when it is read, so you should *always* check.)

If you need to modify it once it's released into the wild, you have a problem.  You need to lock it to write to it, and all the readers need to respect that lock, which means they need to lock it too, which means the readers can no longer read it simultaneously.  **The best way around this** is usually to create a whole new SortedDictionary, then, once the new one is immutable, replace the reference to the original with a reference to the new one.  (You need a volatile reference to do this right.)  The readers will switch dictionaries cleanly without a problem.  And the old dictionary won't go away until the last reader has finished reading and released its reference.

(There are n-readers and 1-writer locks, but you want to avoid any locking at all.)

(And keep in mind the reference to the dictionary can change suddenly if you're enumerating.  Use a local variable for this rather than refering to the (volatile) reference.)

Java has a [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html), which allows any number of simultaneous reads and writes, but I don't think there's anything like it in .NET yet.  And if there is, it's going to be slower for reads than an immutable SortedDictionary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it is not **documented** to be safe. That is the real reason. Reasoning with implementation details is not as good because they are *details* that you cannot rely on.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not safe to do so. If you want to implement in multithreading than you should do this

```
 private readonly object lockObject = new object();
 lock (lockObject )
    {
        //your dictionary operation here.
    }
```